# Illegal pattern character 'T' when use transforms.TimestampConverter.format in kafka jdbc sink connector

Tags: shell, datetime, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I prepare to build a jdbc sink connector to write some data from Kafka to PostgreSQL.

My source data have a timestamp column and value will be like '2022-06-29T04:00:00Z'.

Kafka connector data type doesn't have timestamp so I use transforms.TimestampConverter.format="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" and it's not work.

All error messages are Kafka can't parsing 'T' in timestamp format.

I had tried different transforms.TimestampConverter.format below, but all of these are not work:

1. "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
2. "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"
3. "'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ssZ'"

Does anyone have any idea to solve this?

Environment:

1. Kafka version: 2.6.0
2. confluent JDBC Connector (Source and Sink): 10.5.0
3. Java: openjdk version: 11.0.13

produce message:

```
{'schema': {'type': 'struct',
  'fields': [{'type': 'string', 'field': 'timestamp'},
   {'type': 'string', 'field': 'col_str'},
   {'type': 'int64', 'field': 'col_int'}]},
 'payload': {'timestamp': datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'),
  'col_str': 'test',
  'col_int': 123}}
```

Postgresql table schema:

```
                                                      Table "public.test"
  Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 timestamp | timestamp without time zone |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 col_str   | character varying           |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 col_int   | integer                     |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
Access method: heap
```

Kafka jdbc sink connector config:

```
    curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i 'http://127.0.0.1:8083/connectors' \
    --data \
    '{
        "name":"test_sink_timescale",
        "config":{
            "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
            "connection.url":"jdbc:postgresql://<url>:5432/postgres",
            "connection.user":<user>,
            "connection.password":<password>,
            "topics":"test",
            "auto.create":"false",
            "insert.mode": "insert",
            "table.name.format": "public.test",
            "transforms": "TimestampConverter",
            "transforms.TimestampConverter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
            "transforms.TimestampConverter.format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
            "transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type": "Timestamp",
            "transforms.timestamp.field": "timestamp"
        }
    }'
```

failed log:

```
    [2022-06-29 16:20:19,386] ERROR Failed to start task test_sink_timescale-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:560)
    org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T' for configuration TimestampConverter requires a SimpleDateFormat-compatible pattern for string timestamps: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig.transformations(ConnectorConfig.java:296)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.buildWorkerTask(Worker.java:631)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:555)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startTask(DistributedHerder.java:1251)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.access$1700(DistributedHerder.java:127)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$10.call(DistributedHerder.java:1266)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$10.call(DistributedHerder.java:1262)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T' for configuration TimestampConverter requires a SimpleDateFormat-compatible pattern for string timestamps: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter.configure(TimestampConverter.java:267)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig.transformations(ConnectorConfig.java:285)
            ... 10 more
```

Comment: You could try to escape the `'` with a backslash. `"transforms.TimestampConverter.format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`  is in your config, which is enclosed in `'` which basically removes your `'` around the T

Comment: Do you have any example? 
I have tried "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" or "yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssZ", these are not work for me.

Comment: Is it the same error with backslash escape? Try `"yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ssZ"` (copy exactly as it is for the format value). Should be the 3rd format you tried, but you also added `'` around the whole format, which shouldn't be there

Comment: Try using POSTMan rather than curl, or use `curl -d@config.json` with a file rather than in-line the body

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I try `"yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ssZ"` and have the same problem `Illegal pattern character 'T' for configuration TimestampConverter`.